# Как установить CMS?

Tags: cms

Если кто знаком с Unlabeled CMS, расскажите поподробней, как ее установить???

Comment: в картинках что ли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установка в картинках: [немного скриншотов](http://code.google.com/p/unlabeled/). Вас случайно не забанили на гугле?